# Error al ejecutar php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

Hola gente de stackoverflow, estoy haciendo un proyecto de hospital y me surgió un problema que antes no sucedía. Al necesitar modificar la tabla turnos, al agregarle una nueva columna y tirar el comando php artisan migrate:refresh, me salta el error que dejo acá abajo.

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe> php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2019_06_04_002058_create_turnos_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'turnos' already exists (SQL: create table `turnos` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `fecha_hora` timestamp not null, `paciente_id` int unsigned not null, `medico_id` int unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'turnos' already exists")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:119

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'turnos' already exists")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:117
```

Y al tirar php artisan migrate:refresh me salta este error:

```
Rolling back: 2019_06_03_233709_create_medicos_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `medicos`)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:119

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\SiHoDe\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:117

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Tabla medicos:

```
class CreateMedicosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('medicos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('codigo')->unique();
            $table->string('nombre_apellido');
            $table->string('domicilio');

            $table->unsignedInteger('localidad_id');
            $table->foreign('localidad_id')->references('id')->on('localidades');

            $table->string('telefono');

            $table->unsignedInteger('lugar_desemp_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('lugar_desemp_id')->references('id')->on('lugares_desemp');

            $table->unsignedInteger('especialidad_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('especialidad_id')->references('id')->on('especialidades');


            $table->timestamp('fecha_nacimiento');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('medicos');
    }
}
```

Tabla turnos:

```
class CreateTurnosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('turnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamp('fecha_hora');

            $table->unsignedInteger('paciente_id');
            $table->foreign('paciente_id')->references('id')->on('pacientes');

            $table->unsignedInteger('medico_id');
            $table->foreign('medico_id')->references('id')->on('medicos');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('turnos');
    }
}
```

Ya probé eliminando las claves foraneas en las 2 tablas y sigue tirando el mismo error, ya no sé cual podría ser la solución y por eso recurro a ustedes los machos alfa lomo plateado.
[image: Error al ejecutar migracion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de mensajes de error que no te dejan ni avanzar ni retroceder son comunes cuando hay problemas de caché, o cuando se intentó hacer una modificación y por algún error de sintaxis se realizó otra, o no se realizó nada, y quedó alguna huella de lo que se intentó hacer y corrompe todo el proceso, sin poder hacer nuevas migraciones ni rollbacks.

La solución mas sencilla:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Lo que hace `migrate:fresh` es que simplemente elimina todas las tablas, sin hacer rollback (como sí lo hace `migrate:refresh`), y ejecutar todas las migraciones desde cero.

Podrías complementarlo haciendo una limpieza del caché de la aplicación previamente.

Comment: Lo solucione verificando el AppServiceProvider, que la funcion boot sea asi:
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

Después tire php artisan migrate:fresh y todo solucionado. Muchas gracias igual man !